# What is the purpose of each of the 5 GNU_Smalltalk Packages

Tags: emacs, gnu

The names of the packages are as follows:

1. gnu-smalltalk
2. gnu-smalltalk-common
3. gnu-smalltalk-el
4. gnu-smalltalk-doc
5. gnu-smalltalk-browser

Is there any downside to installing all of them? I already know that after installing gnu-smalltalk-el, emacs detects the smalltalk,.st, file extension and syntax.

Comment: Use `apt-cache search gnu-smalltalk` to see 1 line descriptions.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you. I'm character limited to show all the printout, Here's a sample of what can be shown. gnu-smalltalk - GNU Smalltalk interpreter and image
gnu-smalltalk-browser - GNU Smalltalk browser
gnu-smalltalk-common - GNU Smalltalk class library sources and extras
gnu-smalltalk-doc - GNU Smalltalk info documentation . . .

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consult with https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/gnu-smalltalk and maybe follow links for each package:

> gnu-smalltalk → GNU Smalltalk interpreter and image
> gnu-smalltalk-browser → GNU Smalltalk browser
> gnu-smalltalk-common → GNU Smalltalk class library sources and extras
> gnu-smalltalk-doc → GNU Smalltalk info documentation
> gnu-smalltalk-el → GNU Smalltalk Emacs front-end

Also the *-dev* package may be useful too

> libgst-dev → GNU Smalltalk virtual machine development files

Comment: Great information I've been struggling for about a week analyzing an incomplete package, what ships with the standard Ubuntu distribution. i'm going to make Smalltalk complete before proceeding with my analysis.  thank you.